Formatting issues with the in text citation style of eNeuro/Journal of Neuroscience bst file (Overleaf, BiBTex)
I am preparing a manuscript for preparation to eNeuro in Overleaf, which follows the Journal of Neuroscience citation style. I'm used to using biblatex with a biber backend but this requires BibTex. Fortunately there is already a bibliography .bst style available for jneurosci on Overleaf, however, the citations come out wrong. Where I am expecting tot see a (Smith et al., 2020) it prints [Smith et al.,2020]. So - square brackets and no space after the comma. Also the commands noted in the sty and bst files (e.g. citing only the year, or author) don't work.
For background, I am using zotero integration so have created a references.bib file in BibTex using the plugin. Not using anything reference related in the preamble. In the main text, I would cite a paper like so \cite{paper_identifier} and at the end of the document where I want to print the bibliography I write this
\bibliographystyle{jneurosci} % here load jneurosci.bst
\bibliography{references}

Thanks for your help!

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us always an short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

For anyone wondering: you're also supposed to import the jneurosci package, which I didn't know. So in the preamble just go and this fixes things. Of course I had searched long and hard before posting a question and then found an answer the minute after...
\usepackage{jneurosci}

